# Why dividing by trigonometric functions gives wrong answer when solving trigonometric equations?

Tags: trigonometry

Hello I have a problem with solving Trigonometric equations. Why this is not true for $0\le\theta\le360$

$$2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin\theta$$
$$2\cos\theta=1$$
Set of solutions $\theta=60,360$

and this is ?

$$2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin\theta$$
$$\sin\theta(2\cos\theta-1)=0$$
Set of solutions $\theta=0,60,180,300,360$

Both of those seem to be logical and yet they give different results. Can you tell me when should I notice that I can't divide by $\sin\theta$ or some other trig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin \theta$ can be $0$. Thus, you divide by zero.

Comment: OH my god... and I was struggling with this question for days :D So $$2xy=x$$$$2y=1$$ is also wrong?

Comment: Yes. The correct solution to that equation is $y=1/2$ or $x=0$. Formally, this is $\{(x,y):x=0\text{ or }y=1/2\}$

Comment: @Adrian yes but there is is a nice counterexample, $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)$. In this case dividing by $\cos(x)$ is perfectly fine, since the if $\cos(x)=0$ would imply that $\sin(x)=0$, which is impossible.This is quite often used in school problems.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sin{\theta}=0$, your equation is satisfied whatever value $2\cos{\theta}$ has (not necessarily $1$), which gives you some values of $\theta$. So you have to exclude the solutions to $\sin{\theta}=0$ before you divide by it, which will give you other values.

Comment: Can you check my comment on the answer below?

Comment: If $x \neq 0$, that's still true. If $x=0$, you could have any $y$, so that's true either if $x=0$, or if $x \neq 0$ and $2y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to cancel a factor, check whether it might be zero.