# Given $\cos^2 x = 2 \sin x \cos x$, why can't I cancel $\cos x$ to get $\cos x = 2 \sin x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If I have a function where I know $\cos^2 x = 2 \sin x \cos x$. Why can I not cross out $\cos x$ on both sides, because I get different values for $\cos x = 2 \sin x$?

Comment: Dividing out the cos on each side means you are eliminating the solution of pi/2, but you should be able to glean other solutions from what's left. I could be wrong though, I'll try the problem and get back to this!

Comment: There should be no problem dividing by $\cos x$, provided you include the solutions to $\cos x = 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For the same reason why $\,\cos x\left( \cos x - 2 \sin x\right)=0\,$ is not equivalent to just $\,\cos x - 2 \sin x = 0\,$.

Comment: You might also find the proof of 1 = 2 to be similar. See https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/first1eq2.html

Comment: See [Why dividing by trigonometric functions gives wrong answer when solving trigonometric equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1641809/323744)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct step is as follow

$$\cos^2x = 2\sin x\cos x\iff \cos^2x - 2\sin x\cos x=0\iff \cos x(\cos x - 2\sin x)=0$$

and therefore the original equation is equivalent to the following $2$ equations

$$\cos x=0 \quad \lor \quad \cos x - 2\sin x=0$$

As an alternative, rephrasing that, we can also observe that

$$\cos^2x = 2\sin x\cos x$$

is clearly satisfied for $\cos x=0$ which is a solution then for $\cos x\neq0$ we can cancel out and obtain

$$\cos x = 2\sin x$$

Note that the fact is not specifically related to trigonometric function but is a more general fact indeed

$$f(x)\cdot g(x)=f(x)\cdot h(x)$$

by the same argument is equivalent to the following $2$ equations

$$f(x)=0 \quad \lor \quad g(x)=h(x)$$

Comment: Yes of course indeed I didn’t write that it is a system but those are 2 independent equations.

Comment: The equations are not independent: if one is true, then the other is false.

Comment: With independent I mean that the final solution is the union of the solutions of the two equations. I fully agree with you.

Comment: Yes, of course we both understand that the solution set is the union of the (disjoint) solution sets of the two equations. But that is not what "two independent equations" means. If you simply write a list of equations, without the very important word "or", the meaning is the *conjunction* of those equations.

Comment: Thanks I fix that point in order to be more clear. Bye

Answer (score 1):

You may not divide the two members of an equation by $0$. So you can handle the problem with case analysis:

- if $\cos x=0$, the equation holds;
- else if $\cos x\ne0$, the equation can be reduced to $\cos x=2\sin x$.

Now you solve the two cases independently.